# Installing Agda onto Windows 7

Tags: agda

I'm having trouble running Agda on my windows 7 64-bit pc. I tried running the following commands:

```
cabal install agda
```

and

```
cabal install agda-executable
```

which both work, but I still can't seem to get it going with emacs, can someone help me? I've tried the one click installer from [here](http://agda.cvs.gr.jp/agda/Agda-setup-2.2.6.exe) but it doesn't seem to work, I run into this complaint:

```
C:\agda2\bin\agda2-install.cmd failed.
Code = 1
Incorrect Function
Setup was not completed.

Please correct the problem and run setup again
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `Install Agda (cabal install agda agda-executable),` make sure `agda-mode.exe` is on search path. This required because installer will put something like (shell-command-to-string "`agda-mode.exe locate"`) to .emacs file.
2. run "agda-mode setup".
3. My Emacs bin directory is also on the search path but I'm not sure if it required or not. Anyway, you will get error messages if you'll do something wrong.
4. You will also need Haskell mode (`can be obtained from here https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode`) and you will have to add (`load "c:\\haskell\\dev\\haskell-mode\\haskell-site-file.el"`) to your .emacs file. I load it prior to Agda stuff, I do not really know does load order matter or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have GHC 7.0.4 (with Haskell Platform 2011.4.0.0) and I could install Agda 2.3.0 installer in Win7 64b without problems.

If you have GHC 7.4, you should try Agda 2.3.0.1